# How to retrieve the HTML content of a Google Sites footer with a Google Apps Script?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sites

I cannot find in [documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/sites/site) an equivalent to `getSummary()` or `getTitle()` to retrieve the HTML content of a Google Sites [footer](https://support.google.com/sites/answer/191134?hl=en) (the custom footer editable through `Edit site layout > Custom Footer`).

`getHtmlContent()` only provides the content of the main div `#sites-canvas-main`.

```
var url = 'https://sites.google.com/a/test.net/';  
var site = SitesApp.getSiteByUrl(url);
var infos = {"title": site.getTitle(), "summary": site.getSummary()};
var page = site.getChildByName("home");
var content = page.getHtmlContent();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One solution using [UrlFetchApp](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/url-fetch/url-fetch-app):

```
function GetHtmlFooter() {
  var url = 'https://sites.google.com/a/test.net/'; 
  var content = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url).getContentText("UTF-8");
  var footer = content.match('<div class="sites-subfooter-content"><div dir="ltr">(.*)</div></div></div>')[1];
  return footer;
}
```